# VBA - Run macro in only one column

Tags: vba

I have the code working exactly the way I'd like to, however I don't want it to skip onto another column.  I just want my macro to run inside column C then exit.
I am new to VBA in excel, so please pardon my faults.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
    Sub CopyValuetoRange()
'
' CopyValuetoRange Macro

Dim search_range As Range, Block As Range, last_cell As Range
  Dim first_address$
  Set search_range = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  Set Block = search_range.Find(what:="*", _
    after:=search_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlColumns, searchdirection:=xlDown)
  If Block Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Set Block = Block.CurrentRegion
  first_address$ = Block.Address
  Do
    Block.Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows(2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

    'MsgBox "Next Block Range"
    Set last_cell = Block.Cells(Block.Rows.Count)
    Set Block = search_range.FindNext(after:=last_cell).CurrentRegion
  Loop Until Block.Address = first_address$ 'ActiveSheet.Range("C26").End(xlDown).Row


End Sub
```

Here is something I modified from something I found that will essentially do the same thing, however it puts the first cells value into all cells in the range. And this macro actually stays in Column C, since I found recently because it's not a region, it's a range.

Is there a way to change the following to add a formula to all cells in the range that points to the first cell in the range?

```
Sub Macro5()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RngEnd As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range

        Set Rng = Range("C1")
        Set RngEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlDown)
        If RngEnd.Row < Rng.Row Then Exit Sub

        Set Rng = Range(Rng, RngEnd)

        On Error GoTo ExitSub
        Set Rng = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        For Each rngArea In Rng.Areas
            rngArea.Value = rngArea.Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, 1).Value
        Next rngArea


ExitSub:
    ' Macro will exit here if the range is empty.

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be easier if you describe what you want the macro to do (not what it's not supposed to do).

Comment: My appologies for not being clearer. Start at "C1", look downward for an active cell region, once found select all but the top cell in the current region(within comlumn C only), apply FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C" to each of those cells(essentially making the top cell editable and all the cells below in that region will reflect the same), after changing those cells formula, go to the next active cell region within column C in the downward direction and perform the same thing all over again for that region and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have, it's not pretty but it works. I added a column on both sides then removed them after the macro went through the entire column:

```
Sub CopyFirstCellInRangeInOneColumn()
'
' CopyValuetoRange Macro
Dim search_range As Range, Block As Range, last_cell As Range
  Dim first_address$
  ''
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  ''
  Set search_range = ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
  Set Block = search_range.Find(what:="*", _
    LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlColumns, searchdirection:=xlDown)

  'Set search_range = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  'Set Block = search_range.Find(What:="*", _
  '  After:=search_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell), _
  '  LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlDown)


  If Block Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Set Block = Block.CurrentRegion
  first_address$ = Block.Address
  Do
    Block.Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows(2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

    MsgBox "Next Block Range"
    Set last_cell = Block.Cells(Block.Rows.Count)
    Set Block = search_range.FindNext(After:=last_cell).CurrentRegion
  Loop Until Block.Address = first_address$ 'ActiveSheet.Range("C26").End(xlDown).Row

    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you change your search_range, so that you only search Column C?

```
  Set search_range = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
  Set Block = search_range.Find(what:="*", _
    LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlColumns, searchdirection:=xlDown)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, however that will only work if there's nothing on either side of column C.  What if you have something like this?:
![Valid XHTML](http://i42.photobucket.com/albums/e326/cheapkid1/vbamacro.jpg).

Comment: What if I have cells filled on either side of column C? I just want the macro to focus on column C only.  Please see my valid html link above for example.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @cheapkid1 I saw your image, I just don't understand. Are you saying that you want the code to not change anything outside of column C? If so, you should rethink using CurrentRegion.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying.  Thanks so much, that makes sense.  I'll try a different approach.  Any suggestions what I should use instead??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... if all you are trying to do is update Column C's formulas to be equivalent to `"=R[-1]C"` then running this: `Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown).Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"` will do that for everything except C1. That's how I understand what you're explaning, but it seems too simple to be what you want.

Comment: Unknown ranges within column "C." Each range has a top cell, that cell will be editable for the range to match what you enter. So ie Range 1 will have C3:C10, that means the macro will change C4:C10 equal to "=R[-1]C" so if you enter the number 13 in cell C3, C4:C10 will change to 13 as well.  I want the macro to change all ranges within column "C" to that format.  So the macro will then go to the next set of ranges changing the 2nd from top row in the range Cx:C_range_end "=R[-1]C"...until end of column "C."  I don't know how else to explain it...(shoulder shrug)

Comment: Is there a way I could exit the sub if the range search exceeds column C?  Say if it finishes in C and tries to go to column D, then exit.  Is this possible?  Not too familiar with exit strategies.